# Straight lined scatter over marked scatter plot

Tags: excel, plot, line, scatter

I'm trying to make a simple scatter plot in Excel. One variable are field measures of river flow. The other one is the fitted rating curve (done externally). I draw the field measures as marked scatter plot. For the rating curve I created a column with the water level at each centimeter and the respective water flow calculated with the curve equation. With this pair (water level, water flow) I have added a second series and changed from marked scatter to straight lined scatter plot.

The problem is that I need to see the rating curve **over** the measures plot. I had changed the plot order but didn't work. The marked plot is always over the lined one.

Any suggestion!?

[image: Scatter (marked and straight lined) plots]

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161284/reordering-chart-data-series-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not had success with changing series order causing scatter data to appear behind a line. Even though the order of the Legend will change, the plot order does not appear to be affected.

In order to get your line to appear in front of the scatter data, you will need to put the line on the Secondary Axis, then make sure your min/max values for the secondary axis are the same as the primary.

If you don't want to see the secondary axis set the Label Position to None.

[image]